# Convert c# model to an angular model

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new to angularjs(started today...) and I have an issue with passing model from c# controller to a controller of angularjs.

It seems that I have to call a get method in my angular controller, to call a c# controller from which I will get json and load it to $scope.people for further manipulations:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $http({url: "/Home/GetPersons",method: "GET"
            }).success(function (data) {
                $scope.people = data;
            }).error(function (error) {
                $scope.error = "Failed to load";
        });

     });
</script>
```

Here is my controller :

```
  [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetPersons()
    {
        using (HRMEntities db = new HRMEntities())
        {
            var EmployeeList = db.Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeId >= 0).ToList();

            return Json(EmployeeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

As a response I get error code 500;
What is wrong in the request? And could this be made in easier way? May be using my model which is sent to a view from c# controller `@model List<Employee>`

Comment: 500 means server side error, so you need to debug your method to see what's wrong

Comment: I cant get how to debug it..`EmployeeList` is set, it has 67 elements inside, next step is already return, after which error is shown.

Comment: my best guess is that your EmployeeList contains a circular reference of some kind, so it fails to serialize it. do like this:
`var myJson = Json(EmployeeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
return myJson` 
Does it succeed to create the `myJson` var?

Comment: Creation succeed, myJson.data has 67 elements, but after `return myJson` there still is an error.

Comment: I tend to agree with Joey. Are there any virtual "lazy loaded" properties on your Employee model? If so, you may need to create a DTO or add the [ScriptIgnore] attribute to the virtual properties.

Comment: @GeekyNuns, hmm.. still a 500 error? look at output windowd, may be there's an exception that your debugger is not set to break on. Also if you'll look at Autos Window (while debugging) it will show what your `GetPersons` method returned. But i wonder it returns anything.

Comment: @GeekyNuns, Referring to @Daryl comment, try this one:
`return Json(EmployeeList.Select(x=>{Name=x.Name }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)` still a 500 error?

Comment: I have created new model, and filled it with foreach from `EmployeeList` and it works. So it seems that I cant bind models which are set in my context.tt?

Comment: @j0ey_wh please write an answer so as I could mark it as resolved question :) and thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some discussions, the solution to the problem seems to be this:

```
return Json(EmployeeList.Select(x=>new {Name=x.Name }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Or in other words, creating a Data Transfer Object (DTO) and populating it form `EmployeeList`

Perhaps there were problems with JSON deserialization.

Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Im a little late to this one, but we created this at our company and it is VERY handy to have models that correlate from c# to js (vanilla) and we have angularjs factory model wrappers to extend Domain Model functionality.

https://github.com/castle-it/sharp2Js